# doEval() With Multiline String Argument

Tags: java, mongodb, groovy, gmongo

*Using Groovy 2.3.6, GMongo 1.2, Java 1.8, MongoDB 3.0.0...*

I'm trying to use `doEval()` to get a count of documents in a collection. (For various reasons I want to use `doEval()` rather than `count()`). Invoking `doEval()` with a single line string argument returns retval with a double value of 1.0 and ok with a double value of 1.0 which is what I expect:

```
def str = "db.configurations.count({name: 'Mike'})"
database.doEval(str)
```

If the argument is on multiple lines retval that is returned is null (ok is 1.0).

```
def str = "db.configurations.count({\nname: 'Mike'\n})"
database.doEval(str)
```

I expect doEval to return a retval of 1.0 not null, like in the first example. Is this a bug or is my expectation incorrect? Should `doEval()` support a multiline string argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`doEval()`](https://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DB.html#doEval-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) javadoc:

> Evaluates JavaScript functions on the database server. This is useful
>   if you need to touch a lot of data lightly, in which case network
>   transfer could be a bottleneck.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> `code` - String representation of JavaScript function
>
> `args` - arguments to pass to the JavaScript function

So you are not passing a javascript function to `doEval`method. Anyway, the result you are getting is consistent with the result you can get invoking directly the mongo shell:

```
> db.eval("db.configurations.count({name: 'Mike'})");
1
> db.eval("db.configurations.count({\nname: 'Mike'\n})");
null
```

(I did not dig deeper on mongo shell javascript internals... :-)

Passing a javascript function you can get the result you want:

```
println db.configurations.count([name: 'Mike'])

def str = '''function(name) {
    return db.configurations.count({
        name: name
    });
}'''
println db.doEval(str, 'Mike')
```

The above yields:

```
1
[serverUsed:/127.0.0.1:27017, retval:1.0, ok:1.0]
```